# Javascript works in IE 10, but not FF and Opera

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

The page has two drop-downs fields.

When the first field (`prosent_sikker`) is changed, the other one (`settgradnavn`) should be visible. It works only in IE, not in Firefox and Opera (nothing happens).

- The call to the script from the html code is done on line 54 below.
- The script starts at line 16.

*TESTING*
- The number that is sent into the script, is possible to output using all types of browsers.
- Results from outputing the variables on line 17-19: Totally blank page with IE, and Firefox outputs `null` for all three.

What is wrong?

```
1    <html><head><title>Untitled Document</title>
2    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-12" />
3    <script language="Javascript">
4    <!--
5    function ShowHide(nr) {
6       var nei_v = document.getElementById("nei" + nr); 
7       var prosent_sikker_v = document.getElementById("prosent_sikker" + nr);     
8       var settgradnavn_v = document.getElementById("settgradnavn" + nr); 
9       var vise = nei_v.checked; 
10      if (vise) { prosent_sikker_v.value="Velg";
11                  prosent_sikker_v.style.visibility="hidden";
12              settgradnavn_v.value="Velg";
13                  settgradnavn_v.style.visibility="hidden";}
14      else { prosent_sikker_v.style.visibility="visible";}
15   } 
16   function klikkprosent(nr) {
17      var nei_v = document.getElementById("nei" + nr); 
18      var prosent_sikker_v = document.getElementById("prosent_sikker" + nr);     
19      var settgradnavn_v = document.getElementById("settgradnavn" + nr); 
20      if (prosent_sikker_v.value=="Velg") 
21         { settgradnavn_v.value="Velg";
22           settgradnavn_v.style.visibility="hidden";}
23      else { prosent_sikker_v.style.visibility="visible";
24             settgradnavn_v.style.visibility="visible";}
25   } 
26   //-->
27   </script>
28   <link href='sa_mal_link_2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
29   </head><body>
30   <table border='1' width=984 ><tr><td>
31   <span class='overskr_bl?_18'><b> SIDE 4.S           UTFYLLING AV SP?RRESKJEMAER</b></span><br><br>
32   <table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width=516>
33   <tr valign='bottom'>
34   <td width='265' bgcolor='#FFFF00' align='center'><span class='font_18'>HAR PROBLEMET?</span></td>
35   <td width=28 bgcolor='#FF0000' align='center'><span class='font_18'>NEI</span></td>
36   <td width=92 bgcolor='#3333FF' align='center'><span class='font_18'>JA</span></td>
37   <td width='116' bgcolor='#00CC33' align='center'><span class='font_14'><b>Symptomer</b></span></td>
38   </tr>
39   </table>
40   <div id='Layer1' style='position:relative; width:534px; height:400px;         
41         z-index:1; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 0px solid #0000FF; overflow: scroll;'>
42   <form action='sa_fra_sut.php' method='POST'>
43   
44         <input type='hidden' name='PHPSESSID' value='efn0gm3nf7l8p6sejltd58rgv5'>
45   <table border='1' width=516 cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' class='font_13'>
46   <tr><td width=24 valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF>
47   1</td>
48   <td width=238 valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF>
49   Avf?ringen unormal farge</td>
50   <td valign='top' width=28 bgcolor=#BBDDFF>
51   <input type='checkbox' name='nei0' value='J' onClick='ShowHide("0");'>
52   </td>
53   <td valign='top' width=92 bgcolor=#BBDDFF>
54   <select name='prosent_sikker0' class='saut_font' onChange='klikkprosent(0);'>
55   <option selected='selected' value='Velg'>Velg</option>
56   <option value='100%sikke'>100%sikke</option>
57   <option value='90%sikker'>90%sikker</option>
58   <option value='75%sikker'>75%sikker</option>
59   <option value='50%sikker'>50%sikker</option>
60   <option value='25%sikker'>25%sikker</option>
61   <option value='10%sikker'>10%sikker</option>
62   </select>
63   </td>
64   <td valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF>
65   <script language='Javascript' type='text/javascript'>
66   <!--
67   document.write("<select name='settgradnavn0' class='saut_font' style='visibility: hidden;'>");
68   /*
69   -->
70   document.write("<select name='settgradnavn0' class='saut_font'>");
71   <!-- */  // -->
72   </script>
73   <option selected='selected' value='Velg'>Velg</option>
74   <option value='___'>...................</option>
75   <option value='Ingen'>Ingen</option>
76   <option value='___'>...................</option>
77   <option value='1. Av&til, lett'>1. Av&til, lett</option>
78   <option value='2. Ofte, mildt'>2. Ofte, mildt</option>
79   <option value='3. Av&til,kraftig'>3. Av&til,kraftig</option>
80   <option value='4. Ofte, volds.'>4. Ofte, volds.</option>
81   <option value='___'>...................</option>
82   <option value='1. Litt'>1. Litt</option>
83   <option value='2. En del'>2. En del</option>
84   <option value='3. Mye/mange'>3. Mye/mange</option>
85   <option value='4. Sv?rt mye'>4. Sv?rt mye</option>
86   <option value='___'>...................</option>
87   <option value='1. Noe plags.'>1. Noe plags.</option>
88   <option value='2. Plags.'>2. Plags.</option>
89   <option value='3. Ille'>3. Ille</option>
90   <option value='4.Forferdelig'>4.Forferdelig</option>
91   </select>
92   </td></tr><tr><td width='24' valign='top' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> 2 </td>
93   <td width='200' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> </td>
94   <td width='28' valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF> </td>
95   <td width='92' valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF> </td>
96   <td width='114' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> </td>
97   </tr>
98   <tr><td width='24' valign='top' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> 3 </td>
99   <td width='200' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> </td>
100  <td width='28' valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF> </td>
101  <td width='92' valign='top' bgcolor=#BBDDFF> </td>
102  <td width='114' valign='top' bgcolor='#BBDDFF'> </td>
103  </tr>
104  </table>
105  </div>
106  <div id='Layer2' style='position:absolute; background-color: #CCFF99; width:410px; height:440px;         
107        z-index:1; left: 560px; top: 85px; border: 0px solid; overflow: hidden;'>
108  <table border='1' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>
109  <b>Veiledning</b> <span class='font_13'>(leses N?YE f?r utfylling)</span><br><br><span class='font_13'>
110  Utf?r f?lgende for ALLE linjene:
111  <ol>
112  <li><p>Om du IKKE HAR problemet: <br>Klikk boksen under den <font color='red'>r?de
113                </font> kolonnen 'Nei'.</p></li>
114  <li>Om du HAR problemet: <br>Klikk p? 'Velg' under den <font color='blue'>bl?</font> kolonnen 'JA'.
115                Nytt felt dukker da opp p? linja, fyll ut i henhold til veiledningen nedenfor.</li>
116  <ul type='-'>
117  <li><u>Kolonnen 'JA'</u>: Angi her hvor sikker du er p? at du virkelig har dette problemet.</li>
118  <li><u>Kolonnen 'Symptomer'</u>: Velg 1,2,3 eller 4 fra den serien som passer best. Velg ut fra 
119                         gjennomsnittlig ubehag over tid.</li>
120  </ol>
121  </li>
122  </ol>
123  <u>FULLF?R-Knappen</u>: Klikkes n?r skjemaet er ferdig utfyllt.<br><br>
124  <u>LAGRE og AVSLUTT-Knappen</u>: For ? lagre et delvis utfyllt skjema. Du kan seinere logge inn med 
125        passordet og fullf?re skjemaet.<br><br>
126  <u>AVBRYT-Knappen</u>: Avslutter skjemaet uten ? lagre.<br><br>
127  <u>TILBAKE-Knappen</u>: Sender deg tilbake til siden for valg av sp?rreskjemaer.<br>
128  </span>
129  </td></tr></table>
130  </div>
131  <br><font size=2 color='red'><b>FEILMELDING (linje 1): bla bla bla.</b></font><br><br><table border='1' cellpadding='0' 
132  
133  cellspacing='0'>
134  <tr valign='bottom'>
135  <td width=120 align='left'><input type='submit' name='knapp' value='<-Forrige'></td>
136  <td width=95 align='left'><input type='submit' name='knapp' value='Avbryt'></td>
137  <td width=180 align='left'><input type='submit' name='knapp' value='Lagre og Avslutt'></td>
138  <td align='left'><input type='submit' name='knapp' value='Fullf?r->'></td>
139  </tr>
140  </table>
141  </form>
142  </table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because a name is not an id

```
<select name='prosent_sikker0'
```

You need an id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Terje Valentinsen ,

This is a little bit confusing i suggest you should follow those steps to troubleshoot the problem:

1-Go To http://validator.w3.org/ And try to validate your HTML and try  to fix issues that might affect the script as my friend previously suggested.

2-If the problem persist please check the console of the browsers and try to fix the problem.

3-If you couldn't resolve the problem please edit your post and add the console error.

4-if no error was found please tell me and i will help you fixt the problem.

Thank you for your effort.